# Where does pip save --cert data?

Tags: python, ssl, pip

After trying to do a "pip3 list" on MacOS after installing Python3 with Homebrew and while connected to a corporate network and firewall, I got the below error:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1051)'))) - skipping
```

After some digging, I found this [article](https://superuser.com/questions/727924/pip-and-ssl-certificate-errors). It works! Converting the company's .CER file to .PEM and then doing a "pip3 --cert root-cert.pem list" resolved the issue. However, where does the data get saved? Meaning, how does one revert the setting back to NULL or modify the setting without actually executing the command again using some phony .PEM file?

Comment: What data do you mean? `pip --cert` doesn't append the certificate to the cacert bundle, simply omit the `--cert` option to stop using the cert.

Comment: Where is the "cacert bundle" located on MacOS? Is that the /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem file? Sadly, now that I've used the "pip3 --cert [FILENAME.PEM] list" command and specified a .PEM to use, when I type "pip3 list" it works without SSL warnings even after rebooting. I'm assuming the .PEM file gets saved somewhere. This "somewhere" is what I'm looking for. BTW, when I create a VENV then do a "pip3 list" after activating the virtual environment, I get the original SSL error. Weird.

Comment: Again, calling `pip` with the `--cert` argument does not write any certs; you have done some other modifications to your system, persisting the certificate. On MacOS, the Keychain Access app is used for managing the certs.

Comment: I have the same issue. I ran `pip install --cert path/to/cert module-name` once and that `cert` value is now used for every `pip install` I try to do.